# Downloading on separate machine

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, server, osx-yosemite

I would like to be able to send any downloads from Chrome on my MacBook to my server and download on my server instead. Is there anyway this can be done (I'm sure it isn't too hard).

If there is not already an existing method (I have looked but haven't been successful) could someone kindly point it out. If not, what would I have to know to be able to develop a chrome extension or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad, so my answer will be just an overview.

You can, in principle, write an extension to do this. [`chrome.downloads` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) will allow you to intercept download requests, and you can then send them to a server to download them for you (you'll also need to write a server application for that!) instead of Chrome.

But consider some limitations. Certain sites track how exactly you came to the download link, for instance with referrers, or more esoteric methods. Also, some downloads need authentication (cookies, http auth, etc.) to succeed. It will be harder to try and defeat that, and probably won't work in all cases anyway.

So: it's doable, but it won't be 100% reliable.

Comment: Thanks for this - this is pretty much exactly the answer I was looking for.